How to define initial values for recurrence relation
I was given the following problem : let $f(n,k)$ be the number of possible partitions of $n$ into $k$ different non-negative integers. Find a recurrence relation and initial values for $f(n,k)$.
So I think I found the right relation $f(n,k) = f(n-k+1, k-1) + f(n-k,k)$ but I got very confused trying to figure out what initial values I need to determine. It's clear from the relation formula that the following needs to be satisfied $n \ge k$ and $k \ge 1$ but I'm also required (in the question) to define it for all $n \ge 0$ and $k \ge 1$.
Any ideas on how can I approach this on this particular question and overall on that kind of more complex relation problems?

I think you need to look back it some more. Why do we need $n \geq k$? Why can't we divide the number $3$ into $5$ non-negative integers as follows: $0, 0, 0, 1, 2$?

Notice i wrote different integers

Good point. Then, if $n < k$ (and in other cases), $f(n, k)= 0$, no?

Not necessarily, for example $f(1,2) = 1$ since we can write it as $1 + 0$

Fair enough. Still, you can see that $f(n, k)$ makes sense when $n < k$.
